# How to do IP Canonicalization in .htaccess?

Tags: linux, .htaccess, seo

Today i tested my website on seo tool site and found following error:

Your site's IP xx.xxx.xx.xx does not redirect to your site's domain name. This could cause duplicate content problems if a search engine indexes your site under both its IP and domain name. Consider using a 301 re-write rule in your .htaccess file so that your site's IP points to your domain name.

How can I fix it through .htaccess

Thank You

Comment: This is off-topic for SO; belongs on webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about webmasters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the suggestion is reffererin to redirect yourdomain.com to www.yourdomain.com

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.yourdomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

source: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/modrewrite-tips-tricks.html#Require_the_www

Comment: Question is about IP redirection, not www/no-www redirection.